# How to save subscribed image in any location

Tags: opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone, I am using OpenCV 2.9 and ROS Hydro.
i used this [Publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages) for publish image and used [Subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/SubscribingToImages) for subscribing images. I am able to show that image but how to save it in computer??
I Used imwrite like this after imshow()

```
cv::imwrite("//home//keshav//image.jpg",cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image);
```

p

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197350/how-to-save-subscribed-image-in-any-location/) by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-11-13**:
Add what happend? Error or something?

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-11-14**:
there is no error but also It is not saving any images.
I seached in net somewhere i found that I should use latest opencv for that..but i dont want to install that one.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-11-14**:
Does the folder "//home//keshav//" exist? Usually it should be "/home/keshav/image.jpg" but that should not matter... Does imwrite return true? It should return true on success...

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-11-17**:
hoe to check that one..

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-11-17**:
if ( cv::imwrite("//home//keshav//image.jpg",cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image) ) { ROS_INFO( "Returned true" ); } else { ROS_INFO( "Returned false" ); }

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-11-17**:
try
{
cv::imshow("view", cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg,"bgr8")->image);
cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::BGR8);
if ( cv::imwrite("//home//keshav//image.jpg",cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image) ) { ROS_INFO( "Returned true2" ); } else { ROS_INFO( "Returned false2" ); }
}

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-11-17**:
It is neither returning true nor false.. :-(

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-11-17**:
I have to create ROS nodes, one node can capture images using webcam & 2nd node can publish and third node can subscribe. first am unable to capture also, I can publish and subscribe but imwrite is not working. Mr. Wolf plz share some solid links or code that I can easily execute for this purpose

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-11-17**:
I have done all these job in C using OpenCV and socket communication but now I have to create in ROS only. One more thing I did in C is Serial commands for FTDI Devices, I have to create node for this also, but i will do it later.first I have to capture and publish. Usb_cam, Uvc_cam i tried but ;'-(

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-11-17**:
If it does neither return true nor false, the line you've given is not executed; I guess an exception is thrown before that ; how does your catch statement look like ? is it executed?

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-11-18**:
catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
{
ROS_ERROR("Could not convert from '%s' to 'bgr8'.", msg->encoding.c_str());
}

Nothing is printing on screen.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-11-18**:
If i wanted to publish different images (multiple images) after sleep, How it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just want to save an image, just have a look at the cv_bridge tutorial

http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages

And add a cv::imwrite after the image was converted to cv::Mat:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <sstream>                                                 // Added this

static const std::string OPENCV_WINDOW = "Image window";

class ImageConverter
{
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  image_transport::ImageTransport it_;
  image_transport::Subscriber image_sub_;
  image_transport::Publisher image_pub_;
  
public:
  ImageConverter()
    : it_(nh_)
  {
    // Subscrive to input video feed and publish output video feed
    image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/camera/image_raw", 1, 
      &ImageConverter::imageCb, this);
    image_pub_ = it_.advertise("/image_converter/output_video", 1);

    cv::namedWindow(OPENCV_WINDOW);
  }

  ~ImageConverter()
  {
    cv::destroyWindow(OPENCV_WINDOW);
  }

  void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
  {
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    try
    {
      cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
      ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
      return;
    }

    // Draw an example circle on the video stream
    if (cv_ptr->image.rows > 60 && cv_ptr->image.cols > 60)
      cv::circle(cv_ptr->image, cv::Point(50, 50), 10, CV_RGB(255,0,0));

    // Update GUI Window
    cv::imshow(OPENCV_WINDOW, cv_ptr->image);
    cv::waitKey(3);

    static int image_count = 0;                                // added this
    std::stringstream sstream;                               // added this
    sstream << "my_image" << image_count << ".png" ;                  // added this
    ROS_ASSERT( cv::imwrite( sstream.str(),  cv_ptr->image ) );      // added this
    image_count++;                                      // added this


    // Output modified video stream
    image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_converter");
  ImageConverter ic;
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

This should save you the images with ascending counter locally in the folder where you start the node via rosrun .....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-11-18**:
Thanq Wolf Sir..I think It would work, I will try it. One more question if you help.
I was Using usb_cam driver for capturing image from usb camera. It auto publish (as I understand) when we press right click for saving images? How should I write subscriber for that.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-11-19**:
If I use above code by changing TOPIC name. will it work?

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-11-19**:
jep, that should work...

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-11-20**:
Sorry, Its not working. I saw the [usb_cam](https://github.com/bosch-ros-pkg/usb_cam) files, It is publishing image and camera info, what changes are required in above code.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-11-20**:
What is not working? you need to renap the topic of the usb_cam to /camera/image_raw . Is something published to /image_converter/output_video?

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-11-20**:
One silly doubt I have.. When usb_cam will publish the image? As soon as I will save(by right clicking) or after some time frequently

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-11-24**:
waiting for reply

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-11-24**:
I am not familiar with the usb_cam driver. Typically cam drivers publish at constant frequency. You can check messages are comming using comand "rostopic echo --noarr /your_image_topic" (--noarr skips array data so you can actually see something)